# MongoDB How to fix: Error: couldn't connect to server 197.0.196.205:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to connect remotely on a mongodb server throw my local machine, but i'm having some issues.

On the remote server i modified the 'mongod.cfg' file and i changed the bindIp from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 to allow access. In the same file i changed the security by adding Authentication: 'enabled'.

I created an admin user:

```
> use admin
> db.createUser({user: "root", pwd: "root", roles:["root"]})
```

I started mongodb with --auth flag

```
> mongod --auth --port 27017
```

Once the server was up, i connect to it as administrator

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27017 -u "root" -p "root" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

Once i was connected, i created a normal user

```
> use base
> db.createUser({user: "base", pwd: "base", roles:["dbOwner"]})
```

Then i disconnected from mongo shell and reconnected with new user credentials

```
> mongo 127.0.0.1/base -u "base" -p "base"
```

It worked properly on the remote server.

On the local machine i tried:

```
> mongo <ip address of the server>/base -u "base" -p "base"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
> mongo <ip address>:27017/base -u "base" -p "base"
[js] Error: couldn't connect to server <ip address>:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to <ip address>:27017 :: caused by :: Operation timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be that your local machine and remote server use different versions of MongoDB shell.
Which versions of mongo shell are you using?

You would also need to enclose the connection string in double quotes:

```
mongo "<ip address>:27017/base" -u "base" -p "base".
```

Another issue could be that you need to white list your i.p or configure your firewall rules.